# In WPF, can you hittest segments of a PathFigure?

Tags: wpf, hittest

I'm making a control that involves dragging pieces of a displayed element around.  Since part of it is an arc, I have to use a PathFigure so I can use ArcSegments.  I'd like to be able to know if the mouse is over a particular segment of the figure, but I don't see an obvious way to do this.  Is it impossible or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Owen can please tell us how did u deduce it? Even i have a requirement where i need to know that i have clicked on which PathFigure. My path has multiple PathFugres as below: <Path Stroke="Black"> <Path.Data> <PathGeometry> <PathFigure StartPoint="5,5"> <LineSegment Point="10,10"/> <LineSegment Point="20,60"/> <LineSegment Point="70,90"/> </PathFigure> <PathFigure StartPoint="20,60"> <LineSegment Point="30,20"/> <LineSegment Point="40,70"/> <LineSegment Point="70,80"/> </PathFigure> </PathGeometry> </Path.Data> </Path>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the root Path object has the normal UI events for Mouse, instead of one Path with lots of Arcs you will need lots of Paths with an arc in each.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up deducing this myself and forgot I had asked this question.